# Cross-validation: error estimation and bias

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, dataset, bias, bias-variance-tradeoff

When obtaining the error estimation of a model over a dataset using k-fold cross-validation, lower values of the error estimation necessarily imply a lower bias? Are both concepts, error estimation and bias, equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

Higher test errors can also indicate lower bias, e.g. if the training error is low. So, lower error is not equivalent to lower bias.

Comment: If the test error is what is used as performance estimation, isn't that equivalent to the model bias? Supposedly, if you reduce the test error, then the bias (how far you are from the real performance of the model) must necessarily be reduced, right?

Comment: What if you move from a highly overfitted model (high var, low bias) to a model that gives decent test performance?